How to pass a parameter to VS code extension during development?
This is configuration in .vscode/launch.json that I use to start the extension for debugging:
        {
            "name": "extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
            "cwd": "extension",
        },

And this is what I have in pubspec.json:
"scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
    "compile": "npm run check-types && npm run lint && node esbuild.js",
    "watch": "npm-run-all -p watch:*",
    "watch:esbuild": "node esbuild.js --watch",
    "watch:tsc": "tsc --noEmit --watch --project tsconfig.json",
    "package": "npm run check-types && npm run lint && node esbuild.js --production",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
    "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
    "pretest": "npm run compile-tests && npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "check-types": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "vscode-test"
  },

How can I tweak it to pass flags (compile time is ok) that will say that I need some values to be different?

Yes, watch can be updated in pubspec.json to pass a flag:
"watch": "export FOO=bar && npm-run-all -p watch:*"

